# Which information to provide on a wireless bug report?

Tags: wireless, drivers, diagnostic

I own a Belkin wireless USB adapter. It seems to be supported by the rtl8192cu driver in 11.10 betas, which is great, because in 11.04 the driver had to be compiled/installed manually. But, nobody is perfect, and I seem to have some driver-related problems with the dongle.

It seems that it is able to connect only after several retries (taking the dongle out and plugging it in another port), or after a reboot, or sometimes at the first boot.

I don't know how to diagnose this wireless things from the command line, so I'll tell you what I see in Kubuntu's network manager: When it can't connect, it says "Configuring interface" for a loong time, and then sometimes "Waiting for authorization". Nothing else.

What I'm asking is:

1. What type of information (logs, traces, etc), and
2. How do I exactly get it (where is it, is there a special command like *dmesg*),

in order to

1. try to troubleshoot the problem myself,
2. Have better chances to spot a duplicate bug report.
3. Provide that information in a new bug report.

I'd appreciate as much information as possible regarding this matter, because I've never done it but I've already needed it in the past.

**UPDATE**
I've finally filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-3.0.0/+bug/862684) on this matter. Does anybody know why might be this happening?

Comment: It's a bug as you mentioned and you have filed a bug report :) You officially figured it out yourself :)

Comment: @nitstorm Indeed :) I've got to mention the proprietary driver from Realtek is working.

Comment: @XaviLópez I've reopened it, if you could write a answer explaining how you installed the driver from Realtek, that'd be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally submitted a bug report using [`apport`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport). This command can be used to automatically attach some useful information to a bug. Other logs/information that turned out to be probably relevant were `dmesg`, `lsusb` and `uname` outputs, grepped `lsmod`  to show modules related to the device, and `modinfo` of those modules.

Finally, it turned out that the proprietary driver from Realtek worked fine. The driver can be downloaded from [Realtek's website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772). It seems that Realtek has modified the driver so that it supports newer versions of the kernel. In previous versions, it was necessary to patch a couple of `includes`, as @chicoff pointed out in his answer to the question [Installing Realtek 8188 wireless driver fails](https://askubuntu.com/a/70927/25247), and in [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852190/comments/36) on a similar Launchpad bug report

Realtek's package provides a `sh` installer that compiles and installs the module into the kernel. It's necessary to blacklist the driver included in the kernel, so that it's not eligible for loading when rebooting. See this question for details on how to achieve it: [How to force a proprietary driver to load on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/q/77314/25247).