# Has anyone gotten Edimax 7811 to work under 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, usb, compiling, realtek

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10. Afterwards I needed to have wireless capability on the same machine. The Edimax 7811 is listed as Linux compatible, but it did not work with Ubuntu 11.10. It uses the RealTek 8192CU chip set. I was able to compile the driver that's available on the RealTek website, with help from various forums. The basic steps I followed included the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

downloaded the driver to Desktop from: http://www.edimax.com/en/support_det...id=1&pl2_id=44

cd Desktop/rtl8192CU_8188CU_linux_v2.0.939.20100726/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.939.20100726

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

I got a little ways into the make command before errors started appearing. Evidently this works with 11.04 but the new 3.0 kernel has some differences in it that require some minor changes to the code.

I found this:

"For kernels newer than Maverick, every instance of init_MUTEX should be changed to sema_init. Please amend os_dep/osdep_service.c with a text editor and change line 305 and any other instances and then try again:"

And this:

change smp_lock.h to smp.h for all occurences. Not sure about this one, because there are some special cases for kernel numbers greater than 2.6

I get to the make without problems, but make install returns:

> cp: cannot stat '/autoconf_rtl8192c_usb_linux.h': No such file or
>   directory

I can connect to my router only, but not out to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

to solve the "linux/smp_lock.h not found" error you need to edit this two files into the archive driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922.tar.gz

file 1: include/rtw_io.h

Change osdep_service.h (line 49) `linux/smp_lock.h` to `linux/smp.h`

file 2: include/osdep_service.h

Change file rtw_io.h (line 36) `linux/smp_lock.h` to `linux/smp.h`

- [Installing Realtek 8188 wireless driver fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68198/installing-realtek-8188-wireless-driver-fails)
  this works for me.