# edimax EW-7811Un USB wireless - sees network but fails to connect to it

Tags: wireless

Yesterday I got my first Ubuntu (11.10 32 bit) installation (wish me luck), and I ran into a problem with my USB network card.

I use a wireless USB stick by edimax (it is called IEEE802.11b/g/n nano USB adapter or also EW-7811Un).

My problem is that Ubuntu seems to be able to use the USB to see the networks around me, but when I try to connect to my network - it just keeps trying and failing.

I am connected to the internet through a

300M Wireless N Router Model No. TL-WR841N / TL-WR841ND

I have other computers in the house which are able to connect to the internet. And the same computer previously had Windows on it - and it managed to connect to the internet with no problem.

Can you please advise on how this can be resolved?
(what output should I send you?)

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug report on this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852190. Have you tried to use ndiswrapper to see if you can get it to work with windows drivers?

Comment: Hi Engels - great catch.  I see at the end of the thread that there is a solution, but it is not clear to me where to download it from.  Can you advise?  (THANKS for your help!)

Comment: There is a link in comment #36. :~) Not really sure how it works though. The description says "Linux driver for Kernel 2.6.38(and earlier)", and 11.10 has 3.0.

Comment: Tal you can download the drivers from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CUS and follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/68198/installing-realtek-8188-wireless-driver-fails

Comment: Hi Engels - I just followed the steps on the link you provided - it managed to see the driver correctly, but this didn't fix the problem (e.g: seeing a network - but failing to connect to it).  :(  Any more suggestion to follow would be great.

Comment: I have the exact Edimax model and installed the drivers from Realtek for RTL8192CU. Installed it nicely and the only thing I had to do was blacklist ath and ath5k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o.k., I solved the problem.

It took a bunch of steps - I have detailed them here:

http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Thank you Engels for your kind help! (I also gave credit in the post, and will gladly link to whatever website you might want from your name)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi Ronald,  The essentials are already answered in the linked question in the comments.  I didn't add to the core of the answer, but organized it a bit.  You are welcome to edit my answer as you please :)

Comment: In your link there, it says to blacklist the rtl8192cu (or approximate) driver which is the driver I have currently functioning (same model and everything). I had to instead blacklist ath and ath5k.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how useful this answer will remain if the link becomes unavailable.

Comment: This doesn't work with recent (3.10+) kernels because the driver code doesn't compile anymore. (implicit declaration of function 'create_proc_entry'). Does anyone have a fixed version?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Edimax EW-7811Un` then the following (qouted from this [site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=61665)) should fix the problem:

Create this file `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` and and the following lines to it:

```
# Disable power management
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0
```

Then save it and reboot and the wifi adapter should work properly.

For more details about the above parameters and their values:

```
rtw_power_mgnt=0|1|2
---------------------------------
    0 == disable power saving
    1 == power saving on, minPS
    2 == power saving on, maxPS

rtw_enusbss=0|1
---------------------------------
    0 == disable auto suspend
    1 == enable auto suspend
```