# RTL8192CU wont re-activate automatically after reboot

Tags: 12.04, wireless

After a long search I found a driver that works for my TP-Link USB wireless device (TP-WN723N). It's super stable,Tx/Rx is brilliant. But...Every time I reboot, I have to go into proprietary drivers, deactivate, and then reactivate to get it to work again. I'm using an RTL8192CU driver and Ubuntu 12.04. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? It's really messing with my pip.

Comment: Can you post the usual troubleshooting info: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`, `ifconfig`, `rfkill list all`. Please use pastebin, if you can't edit the question. Can you also explain what the driver you've found has to do with going "into proprietary drivers".

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79818/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-sees-network-but-fails-to-connect-to-it) & [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/).

Blacklisting the wrong driver was key for me, otherwise system defaults to wrong driver.

Comment: Can you please include the essential steps, just dropping links is not very helpful.