# Trouble with getting edimax ew-7811un drivers installed on older dell desktop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu and was expecting just to have a plug and play wireless usb adapter so I can surf the web but I was wrong. I do not know where to start and I hope someone can help get me going.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening `Additional Drivers` to see if Ubuntu proposes proprietary drivers for this wireless device.

See also:

- [edimax EW-7811Un USB wireless - sees network but fails to connect to it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79818/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-sees-network-but-fails-to-connect-to-it?rq=1)
- [Compile and install rtl8192cu driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246236/compile-and-install-rtl8192cu-driver)

Comment: I think there has always been an issue with this particular  kernel driver thus the second links  answers seem logical