# Edimax EW-7622UMn wireless installation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

Hello good people of the Ubuntu universe I'm stuck installing drivers for a Edimax EW-7622UMn I have extracted the tar-tgz file but have no idea what I need to type in to Terminal. If anyone can help? So I can just copy and paste the exact command line it would be massively appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/80140/299605

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing common Wifi drivers in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```