# How to force a proprietary driver to load on startup?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, startup, blacklist, modules

I've been having some problems with the driver for a wireless NIC supplied with the 3.0.0 kernel. I've compiled and installed the proprietary driver for it, so that I can switch it once the system has booted with:

```
# Remove the driver included with the kernel
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu
# Use the proprietary driver
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

The module locations are

- rtl8192cu : /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
- 8192cu (proprietary driver): /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192cu.ko

I know these are probably very basic questions, but I'd like to know about the following:

1. Why is the system using the driver included with the kernel ? Is it because its path has some kind of priority? Or because it is included by default with the kernel?
2. Is blacklisting the `rtl8192cu` module the right way to make the propietary `8192cu` module load at startup?
3. Is there any other way to make the system automatically load the proprietary driver by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is included with the kernel as a module, unless you blacklist the old module, it is loaded at the boot time because of having a device using that module. After installing an other driver, you need to blacklist the old one.

Blacklisting is the right way. But you should add the new module to /etc/modules file.

Comment: Why would it be recommendable to move the module to `/etc/modules`? Is it  because it's a custom driver I've built, not a system one? And how could I do this?

Comment: You won't move the module. /etc/modules is a file not a directory. You had already installed the module but system does not know that module must be loaded at boot. So you will add your module to /etc/modules file as a seperate line.

Comment: Oh, great, now I get what you meant. This answers my 3rd question perfectly. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem for misunderstanding, I am glad it is clear now :)