# How to force a proprietary driver to load on startup (revisited)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, startup, modules, blacklist

I have the exact same problem as [How to force a proprietary driver to load on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77314/how-to-force-a-proprietary-driver-to-load-on-startup)

but the solution does not work for me.

I have

```
~$ tail -7 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
install rtl8192cu /bin/false
install rtl8192c_common /bin/false
install rtlwifi /bin/false

blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist rtlwifi
```

and

```
~$ tail /etc/modules 
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc
8192cu
```

but my device

```
~$ lsusb | grep D-
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2001:3308 D-Link Corp.
```

keeps on using the kernel's default driver:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network | tail -7
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:5
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: 84:c9:b2:75:a1:28
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu ip=192.168.0.19 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

instead of the propriety driver:

```
~$ lsmod | grep 8192
8192cu                547185  0 
~$ modinfo 8192cu
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192cu.ko
version:        v3.4.4_4749.20121105
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     657E53E8FE213B566819C54
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8186d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9021d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17ABd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0061d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v20F4p624Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v050Dp2103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v050Dp2102d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v4855p0091d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0056d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8178d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v7392p7822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3309d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019p1201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFBd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF9d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF7d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3358d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3359d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp317Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019p4902d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v4856p0091d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp5088d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p005Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3357d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v4855p0090d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v20F4p648Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1102d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3308d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v103Cp1629d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v06F8pE033d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0EB0p9071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8189d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v7392p7811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019pED17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8178d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8177d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp018Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp818Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8754d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8170d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8176d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8191d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.2.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           ifname:charp
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_cbw40_enable:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_force_iol:Force to enable IOL (bool)
parm:           rtw_intel_class_mode:The intel class mode [0: off, 1: on] (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
```

even after reboot.

edit

I later realized that I blacklisted `rtl8192c_common` instead of `rtl8192c-common`. when doing a `modinfo rtl8192cu` one can see the dependencies:

```
~$ modinfo rtl8192cu | grep dep
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211,rtl8192c-common
```

These in turn:

```
~$ modinfo rtlwifi | grep dep
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
~$ modinfo mac80211 | grep dep
depends:        cfg80211
~$ modinfo rtl8192c-common | grep dep
depends:        mac80211
~$ modinfo mac80211 | grep dep
depends:        cfg80211
~$ modinfo cfg80211 | grep dep
depends:
```

So in the mean time I have modified my `blacklist.conf` to look like:

```
~$ tail -5 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c-common
blacklist rtlwifi
blacklist mac80211
blacklist cfg80211
```

but it makes no difference

/edit

Comment: you are telling it to load 8192cu on boot do you not want that?

Comment: What are in `install` commands in the `blacklist.conf`? Why are they there? All you have to do is blacklist `rtl8192cu`, nothing else. On the second though, what makes you think that it didn't work?

Comment: strings - yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve - for the 8192cu driver to be loaded at boot time. But, as can be seen from the output of `sudo lshw -C network`, the rtl8192cu driver is loaded instead

Comment: mikewhatever, I read somewhere that if the blacklist commands are used in `blacklist.conf`, the kernel might still load those modules under certain conditions. The `install <module> /bin/false` command tells the kernel to never install the module apparently. But as you can see, I've tried both - it makes no difference.

Comment: And to answer your last question, the thing that makes me think it didn't work, is the fact that a, the output of `lshw -C network` and `dmesg` tells me that the `rtl8192cu` driver is used instead of `8192cu`, and b, after insertion of another USB device, I experience the same issues as many who had to install the proprietry driver to get the device to function properly. (see e.g. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861463))